# Erro ao instalar biblioteca textract com conda

Tags: python

Estou tentando instalar a biblioteca TEXTRACT do python, mas está constando o seguinte erro:
Alguém sabe me dizer o que posso fazer para resolver isso?

Solving environment: failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

- jeepney
- textract
  -

Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: tem feito atualização desses pacotes ?

Comment: Na verdade eu não irei utilizar a biblioteca jeepney, apenas a textract... porém, quando vou instalar aparece esse problema. Até instalei a jeepney para ver se resolvia, mas não adiantou..

Comment: ja fez a tentativa de uso apenas com o textract? e a minha resposta? você atualizou esses algum desses pacotes ?

Comment: Sim, havia feito.. agora eu desinstalei o jeepney e deu certo.. parece que ambos não funcionam juntos.. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A utilização do pacote/package `jeepney` e `textract` não funcionam simultaneamente. principalmente após atualizações. Desinstale um, se não der certo, desinstale a ultima atualização.

Comment: Gostaria de adicionar mais um comentário, visto que consegui instalar a biblioteca textract apenas quando a instalei com o pip, pip install textract... Obrigada pela ajuda!